# HTTP 500 ошибка при передаче GET-параметров

Tags: веб-программирование

Старница:

```
https://domain/wr/site1
```

Ее код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
       <script type='text/javascript'>      
        document.onreadystatechange = function () { 
            alert(" TEST");
         }    
      </script>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

При переходе по указанной ссылке странциа отработает нормально и появится  сообщение.
Но если туда еще передать параметры:

```
https://domain/wr/site1?param1=dxdcfvgbhnj
```

То получаю 500ую ошибку:

> HTTP Error 500 - Internal Server Error

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, ведь мой второй запрос - тот же GET но с параметрами, почему не работает? 
С моей точки зрения, результат должен быть одинаковым для обеих ссылок.**

Про сервер, ан котором старница эта крутится, к сожалению, сведений нет.

Спасибо

Comment: Ошибка 500 - это как раз ошибка сервера, там её искать и надо. Видимо, серверная часть неправильно обрабатывает параметры.

Comment: Потому что сервер может быть реализован как угодно, в том числе падать при передаче `param1`. Больше без кода сервера сказать ничего путного нельзя

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки